# Specifiying proxy to sign jars with maven with maven-antrun-plugin

Tags: java, maven, ant, proxy, maven-antrun-plugin

I want to use the following maven-script to sign my jars for a webstart application:

```
<plugin>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>signWebJars</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/signedjars" />
                    <signjar destDir="${project.build.directory}/signedjars"
                        tsaurl="http://timestamp.my-tsa-url.com"
                        alias="server" keystore="src/main/assembly/MyKeystore.jks"
                        storepass="password" preservelastmodified="true" lazy="true">
                        <path>
                            <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/dependenciesForSign"
                                        includes="*.jar" />
                        </path>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

As I am behind a proxy I configured one in the settings.xml and maven can access to the internet. Now I need to contact the tsaurl of the certificate authority. But for the given ant tasks this is not working:

```
  [signjar] jarsigner: unable to sign jar: no response from the Timestamping Authority. When connecting from behind a firewall then an HTTP proxy may need to be specified. Supply the following options to jarsigner: 
  [signjar]   -J-Dhttp.proxyHost=<hostname> 
  [signjar]   -J-Dhttp.proxyPort=<portnumber>
```

I tried to provide the proxy information to the ant task but this was not working. In the manual of the [Ant Signjar Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html) I just found: Ant does not yet support proxy setup for this signing process.

How may I get this working? Or do you suggest another way to sign all jars in a folder - of course with proxy support?

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Comment: No but found a way to go without proxy. Will switch to maven sign jar plugin which can sign all dependencies of my project AMD not only the projects artifact jar.

Answer (score 0):

Try https instead of http
e.g. -Dhttps.proxyHost= -Dhttps.proxyPort=